# Is vertical orientation for the jssor carousel possible?

Tags: slider, carousel, jssor

I'm messing around with jssor but can't figure out if i can get the carousel as on the demo pages in vertical mode? Is an orientation switch even possible with jssor sliders?

Answer (score 1):

Please use $PlayOrientation and $DragOrientation option,

See [jssor slider options](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html)

Answer (score 1):

When initializing "jssor_slider" just add "$PlayOrientation" and "$DragOrientation" to options variable like: (+$AutoPlay - for slideshow)

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: true, // to enable slideshow, set to true.
        $PlayOrientation: 2, // orientation of slides, 2 vertical
        $DragOrientation: 2 // orientation of slide drag, 2 vertical
    };
    var jssor_slider = new $JssorSlider$('slider_container', options);
});
```

In addition to above you can specify aditional options..

Just like **jssor** mentioned previously - [jssor slider options](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html)

You can achive slider with slideshow with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: true,
        $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                $ShowLink: true
            } 
    };
    var jssor_slider = new $JssorSlider$('slider_container', options);
});
```

Hope it helps..